# How to make my own javascript Math method working?

Tags: javascript, math, methods

In javascript when I create this function it does what can be expected :

```
Number.prototype.powown = function(b) {
    return Math.pow(this, b);
}
var a = 3;
var b = 6;
document.write(a.powown(b));
```

But I want to have it working without the use of variables, I can't figure out how this works.

I would like to make it work when I give this code :

> document.write(Math.powown(3,6));

Comment: In that case there's no difference between pow and powown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `Math` object already have [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) you could directly use it, in case you want to add custom functions , you could add custom function to [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) object, for example:

```
Math.powown = function() {
  return Math.pow(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
};
console.log(Math.powown(2,2)); //gives 4
```

Comment: `Math.powown = Math.pow` would have the same effect using less code ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example works perfect for me. Unfortunatly I have no 15 reputation to vote this answer up.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this

```
Number.prototype.pow = function(a){ return Math.pow(this, a); }
```

So you can then call it like this

```
(10).pow(5);
```

or this

```
10..pow(5);
```

*Note:*
You wont be able to call `10.pow(5)` the parenthesis or . are required for javascript to know 10 is Number

*Bonus:*
If you wanted to get really silly you could apply all the methods of Math to the prototype of Number like this.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math).forEach(function(p){
    Number.prototype[p] = function(){
        return Math[p].apply(null, Array.prototype.concat.apply([this], arguments));
    }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly the function I had created. But in addition you gave me the right line to call the function. Thanks for that. But there is a better looking solution given.

Comment: DemoUser's answer duplicates the pow method on the Math object and, as pawel pointed out, has exactly the same effect of just setting Math.powown = Math.pow